# How to read data from JSON file in Slim microframework?

Tags: php, slim

how to read data from file in Slim framework? For example, the code below works in usual php app:

```
<?php
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\s1\vendor\me.json'), true);
print data["data"][0]["id"];
```

But how to do the same in Slim? I write:

```
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->get('/test/', function(Request $reg, Response $res, $args = []){
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\s1\vendor\me.json'), true);
return $res->$data["data"][0]["id"];
});
$app->run();
```

And I got nothing. Please, tell me how to fix it, ant ideas?

Comment: `I got nothing` means even not any errors? Because both your codes should raise errors. Your first code should not work because you have a syntax error, you forgot `$` in `print data`. In your second code the usage of `$res->$data` is should raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems inn your code.

You're decoding the JSON string and putting it in `$data`:

```
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\s1\vendor\me.json'), true);
```

but you're trying to return something from `$res->$data`:

```
return $res->$data["data"][0]["id"];
```

which is not correct.

You need to return `$data["data"][0]["id"]` or write it to response body and return the response:

```
$app->get('/test/', function(Request $reg, Response $res, $args = []){
    $data= json_decode(file_get_contents('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\s1\vendor\me.json'), true);
    $res->getBody()->write($data["data"][0]["id"]);
    return $res;
});
```

Also, you're defining your route as `/test/` with trailing `/`, this means you **MUST** access this route with the trailing slash like `localhost/test/` otherwise you'll get a `404` error. I suggest removing the trailing `/` in definition.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
$app->get('/test/', function(Request $reg, Response $res, $args = []){
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\s1\vendor\me.json'), true);
$res->write($data["data"][0]["id"]);
return $res;
});
```

Comment: Nothing happened

Comment: Nothing happened again